# How to execute a python file from another

Tags: python

I have two python files.

I need to call the 2nd one from 1st.

I'm aware of os.system() commands.

But it's been mentioned as the worst way to execute a python script.

The script I need to call doesn't contain any functions or classes. but just the flow.

what is the better way to execute the script from another script.

Comment: Importing a python file is not the same as "executing" a python file which may be its own program with command line arguments, side-effects, different Python version, etc. This is not the same question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put both files in the same directory.
2. Add an empty file called `__init__.py` in the directory.
3. Then in the first file just include this: `from file2 import myfunction`
4. You can then call `myfunction` from `file2` in `file1`.

Answer (score 0):

> by importing you execute everything in your other .py file that is outside a function.

if im inside *template.py* but want to run code inside *test.py* that for example only opens a gui window, all i need to do is type `import test` and have the map structure like this
[image]